# Python: building new list from existing by dropping every n-th element

Tags: python, list

I want to build up a new list in which every n-th element of an initial list is left out, e.g.:

from `['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh']`
make `['second', 'third', 'fifth', 'sixth'` because `n = 3`

How to do that?
Is it - first of all - correct to accomplish this by building up a new list, instead of trying to delete? For the latter I tried with `deque` and `rotate` but that ended up in confusion.
To build up a new list I was trying something with `range(1,len(list),n)` but that are the element positions to be deleted and not the ones which are to be kept for the new list.

How do I get my desired list?

Comment: Are you deleting them in a circular way?

Comment: Hai Vu nailed it, it's exactly what I wanted. (Jon S. and 
Muhammad Alkarouri meant the same, I guess)

Comment: Well, I gave the same answer more than 8 minutes before him. What was the problem?

Comment: @solarisman If I were you then I should've accepted Muhammad Alkarouri's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16406859/846892), Hai Vu answer is simply a copy(may be not intentional) of it.

Comment: Muhammad Alkarouri, you are the man! Just gave you the green tick. Guys, you are just too fast for me to read and understand.

Comment: No worries, solarisman. And thanks for the cool head, @AshwiniChaudhary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> [s for (i,s) in enumerate(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh']) if i%3]
['second', 'third', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```

The answer in a few steps:

The `enumerate` function gives a list of tuples with the index followed by the item:

```
>>> list(enumerate(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh']))
[(0, 'first'), (1, 'second'), (2, 'third'), (3, 'fourth'), (4, 'fifth'), (5, 'sixth'), (6, 'seventh')]
```

then you check if the index does not divide by three, and if so you include the item.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new list and filter at the same time:

```
>>> li = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh']
>>> new_list = [item for index, item in enumerate(li) if index % 3 != 0]
>>> new_list
['second', 'third', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```

#### Discussion

`enumerate(li)` returns a list of tuple: (index, item):

```
[(0, 'first'), (1, 'second'), (2, 'third'), (3, 'fourth'), (4, 'fifth'), (5, 'sixth'), (6, 'seventh')]
```

We only pick out those items with index % 3 != 0, which means dropping items with index 0, 3, 6, ...

#### Update: A Different Solution

If you don't mind using itertools:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.compress(li, itertools.cycle(range(3))))
['second', 'third', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```

The `cycle(range(3))` returns an infinite list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...]
```

`compress()` picks out those items that is not zero.

Comment: Yep. The short of the story is that I turned out to be somewhat impertinent. Apologies.

Comment: I am sorry for sounding a little harsh.

Answer (score 2):

I throw in a variant using extended slices:

```
>>> li=['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh']
>>> nl=[None]*(len(li)*2/3)
>>> nl[0::2],nl[1::2]=l[1::3],l[2::3]
>>> nl
['second', 'third', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```

You can also use itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*zip(l[1::3],l[2::3])))
['second', 'third', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehensions to do this.

```
def drop_items(l, n):
    return [x[1] for x in enumerate(l) if x[0] % n]
```

Explanation:

We want to return all items where the index is not a multiple of n. Therefore, I use enumerate to walk over the list, because this lets me use the index as well as the items. An item is not a multiple of n if

```
index % n != 0
```

Therefore, I use this as the condition of whether or not to include the item in my new list.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be complete, you could use filter:

```
>>> l=['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh']
>>> [t[1] for t in filter(lambda t: t[0]%3, enumerate(l))]
['second', 'third', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```