# Python: How to index every nth interval of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

*(complete code snippet at the end of the question)*

I've got a pandas dataframe with unwanted values that occur in a regular interval with a regular distance between them. How can I index them and remove or replace them with for example `np.nan`? The answers to the question [Python: how to remove/delete every n-th element from list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925532/python-how-to-remove-delete-every-n-th-element-from-list/43712428) shows several ways to remove every `n`th element from a list. But what if `n` is not an ***integer***, but an ***interval***? I was sure that for `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, that perhaps `a[k-1::k]` would be a good starting point

But if I've got a dataframe such as:

```
                  date  data
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00    66
1  2020-01-01 01:00:00    92
2  2020-01-01 02:00:00    98
3  2020-01-01 03:00:00    17
4  2020-01-01 04:00:00    83
5  2020-01-01 05:00:00    57
6  2020-01-01 06:00:00    86
7  2020-01-01 07:00:00    97
8  2020-01-01 08:00:00    96
9  2020-01-01 09:00:00    47
10 2020-01-01 10:00:00    73
11 2020-01-01 11:00:00    32
12 2020-01-01 12:00:00    46
13 2020-01-01 13:00:00    96
14 2020-01-01 14:00:00    25
15 2020-01-01 15:00:00    83
16 2020-01-01 16:00:00    78
17 2020-01-01 17:00:00    36
18 2020-01-01 18:00:00    96
19 2020-01-01 19:00:00    80
20 2020-01-01 20:00:00    68
21 2020-01-01 21:00:00    49
22 2020-01-01 22:00:00    55
23 2020-01-01 23:00:00    67
```

And run:

```
k1=10
df.iloc[k1-1::k1]=np.nan

k2=11
df.iloc[k2-1::k2]=np.nan
```

Then I get:

```
                  date  data
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00  66.0
1  2020-01-01 01:00:00  92.0
2  2020-01-01 02:00:00  98.0
3  2020-01-01 03:00:00  17.0
4  2020-01-01 04:00:00  83.0
5  2020-01-01 05:00:00  57.0
6  2020-01-01 06:00:00  86.0
7  2020-01-01 07:00:00  97.0
8  2020-01-01 08:00:00  96.0
9                  NaT   NaN
10                 NaT   NaN
11 2020-01-01 11:00:00  32.0
12 2020-01-01 12:00:00  46.0
13 2020-01-01 13:00:00  96.0
14 2020-01-01 14:00:00  25.0
15 2020-01-01 15:00:00  83.0
16 2020-01-01 16:00:00  78.0
17 2020-01-01 17:00:00  36.0
18 2020-01-01 18:00:00  96.0
19                 NaT   NaN
20 2020-01-01 20:00:00  68.0
21                 NaT   NaN
22 2020-01-01 22:00:00  55.0
23 2020-01-01 23:00:00  67.0
```

So for the first replacement, the values at index [9,10] are replaced with `Nan`. But for the second replacement I get this:

```
19                 NaT   NaN
20 2020-01-01 20:00:00  68.0
21                 NaT   NaN
```

How can I index the dataframe so that index `20` is assigned `Nan` and not index `21`? And how can I make this stable for every tenth and eleventh value (so in this case the length of the interval is 2) if I've got a bigger dataframe?

**Desired output:**

```
                  date  data
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00  66.0
1  2020-01-01 01:00:00  92.0
2  2020-01-01 02:00:00  98.0
3  2020-01-01 03:00:00  17.0
4  2020-01-01 04:00:00  83.0
5  2020-01-01 05:00:00  57.0
6  2020-01-01 06:00:00  86.0
7  2020-01-01 07:00:00  97.0
8  2020-01-01 08:00:00  96.0
9  2020-01-01 09:00:00  47.0
10                 NaT   NaN
11                 NaT   NaN
12 2020-01-01 12:00:00  46.0
13 2020-01-01 13:00:00  96.0
14 2020-01-01 14:00:00  25.0
15 2020-01-01 15:00:00  83.0
16 2020-01-01 16:00:00  78.0
17 2020-01-01 17:00:00  36.0
18 2020-01-01 18:00:00  96.0
19 2020-01-01 19:00:00  80.0
20                 NaT   NaN
21                 NaT   NaN
22 2020-01-01 22:00:00  55.0
23 2020-01-01 23:00:00  67.0
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(123)
dates = pd.date_range("2020.01.01", "2020.01.02", freq="1h")
dates=dates[:-1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates,
                   'data':np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=len(dates)).tolist()})

# indexing attempts
k1=10
df.iloc[k1-1::k1]=np.nan

k2=11
df.iloc[k2-1::k2]=np.nan

df
```

Comment: You are doing in the correct way, but not maintaining a constant step size that you want here is `10`, which will give your desired output? So, keep three variable `k1, k2 and step_size` and your code will be `df.iloc[k1-1::step_size]=np.nan;df.iloc[k2-1::step_size]=np.nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need for each `10th` value use starting by `10` value with step `10` and for second starting by `11th` value and step same - `10`:

```
k1=10
df.iloc[k1::10]=np.nan
k2=11
df.iloc[k2::10]=np.nan
```

Your solution create each `11th` value (step 11), so it is expected output.

EDIT: You can use modulo and integer division for set each `11` and `12` rows with omiting first and second row by:

```
r = np.arange(len(df))
mask = np.in1d(r % 10, [0,1]) & (r // 10 > 0)

df[mask] = np.nan
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
dates = pd.date_range("2020.01.01", "2020.01.02", freq="30T")
dates=dates[:-1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates,
                   'data':np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=len(dates)).tolist()})


k1=10
df.iloc[k1::10]=np.nan
k2=11
df.iloc[k2::10]=np.nan
```

---

```
print (df)
                  date  data
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00  66.0
1  2020-01-01 00:30:00  92.0
2  2020-01-01 01:00:00  98.0
3  2020-01-01 01:30:00  17.0
4  2020-01-01 02:00:00  83.0
5  2020-01-01 02:30:00  57.0
6  2020-01-01 03:00:00  86.0
7  2020-01-01 03:30:00  97.0
8  2020-01-01 04:00:00  96.0
9  2020-01-01 04:30:00  47.0
10                 NaT   NaN
11                 NaT   NaN
12 2020-01-01 06:00:00  46.0
13 2020-01-01 06:30:00  96.0
14 2020-01-01 07:00:00  25.0
15 2020-01-01 07:30:00  83.0
16 2020-01-01 08:00:00  78.0
17 2020-01-01 08:30:00  36.0
18 2020-01-01 09:00:00  96.0
19 2020-01-01 09:30:00  80.0
20                 NaT   NaN
21                 NaT   NaN
22 2020-01-01 11:00:00  55.0
23 2020-01-01 11:30:00  67.0
24 2020-01-01 12:00:00   2.0
25 2020-01-01 12:30:00  84.0
26 2020-01-01 13:00:00  39.0
27 2020-01-01 13:30:00  66.0
28 2020-01-01 14:00:00  84.0
29 2020-01-01 14:30:00  47.0
30                 NaT   NaN
31                 NaT   NaN
32 2020-01-01 16:00:00   7.0
33 2020-01-01 16:30:00  99.0
34 2020-01-01 17:00:00  92.0
35 2020-01-01 17:30:00  52.0
36 2020-01-01 18:00:00  97.0
37 2020-01-01 18:30:00  85.0
38 2020-01-01 19:00:00  94.0
39 2020-01-01 19:30:00  27.0
40                 NaT   NaN
41                 NaT   NaN
42 2020-01-01 21:00:00  76.0
43 2020-01-01 21:30:00  40.0
44 2020-01-01 22:00:00   3.0
45 2020-01-01 22:30:00  69.0
46 2020-01-01 23:00:00  64.0
47 2020-01-01 23:30:00  75.0
```

Comment: I see now that I may not have explained the issue well enough. I'll edit in a desired output. Just give me 2 minutes

Comment: @jezreal Thank you for answering! That certainly creates the desired output. But do you know if it's possible to do this through a direct indexing, and not in two steps. I suspect that the answer is no, but I'm just really curious about this.

Comment: @vestland - Not sure if possible by indexing, I try find some another solution.

Comment: @vestland - added solution with mask with integer and modulo division.

Answer (score 1):

> So for the first replacement, the values at index [9,10] are replaced with Nan.

No. After

```
k1=10
df.iloc[k1-1::k1]=np.nan
```

the relevant indexes are `list(range(k1-1, len(fd), k1)` so 9, 19

And for `k2=11`, the indices are `list(range(k2-1, len(fd), k2)` so 10, 21

What you want is

```
k1=9
df.iloc[sum([[i, i+1] for i in range(k1, len(df), 10)], [])]
```

you can avoid the `sum` on lists with:

```
df.iloc[i+j for j in (0,1) for i in range(k1, len(df), 10)], [])]
```

Comment: Don't use sum to concatenate lists. It looks fancy but it's quadratic and should be considered bad practice.

Comment: @jezrael: Thank you for noticing, because I was not aware of that. I provided another way.