# How to discard every third element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Assume I have a list like

```
l=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I need to discard the first element, then keep the next two elements, then discard the next element, keep the next two elements...etc - doing this across the entire output. Expected output would therefore be:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

It could be saved as a separate list or it could be saved in the same list `l`. How do I do it in single line?

I tried `l[::2]` but the list got saved as

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

while I was expecting something like

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "saving next two elements?"

Comment: what do you mean discard first element, in your expected output you are discardign internal elemeent also

Comment: There's clearly more to your logic than "discarding the first item in a list". You seem to want to discard the first value from a sequence of identical values, or something of that sort. Please clarify more.

Comment: I assume you want something like [1:3]

Comment: @deceze I think OP simply wants to discard every 3rd element starting from the first.

Comment: @GavinWong I mean to say, if I segment the entire index into group of 3 elements each, I want to discard the first element and group the next two elements in the list. I am only interested in the index 1 and 2 and I am not interested in index 0.

Comment: I want to do this over the entire list, within all the segments

Comment: In other words, you want to discard every 3rd element (starting with the 0th)…?

Comment: @deceze yes. That is precisely what I want to do

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736849/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[l[x] for x in range(1,len(l)) if x%3!=0]

#output
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

It will start from 1 by skipping the 0th element then it will skip every 3rd element.

It is more pythonic to use enumerate:

```
[y for x,y in enumerate(l,1) if x%3!=0]
```

or

```
[l[x] for x,y in enumerate(l,1) if x%3!=0]
```

#output

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: If you gonna `enumerate`, then also use `y`!

Comment: Now you also need to start the enumeration at 0 though, otherwise the values are off.

Comment: and `if x%3!=0` is equivalent to `if x%3`

Comment: so basically we need positions `1,2,4,5,7,8`. We do not need `0,3,6,9`, etc. right?

Comment: if I run this command `[x for x,y in enumerate(l,1) if x%3!=0]` I get `[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]`     this means I need to start my `enumerate` from `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```py
l=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
dummy = -1

new_l = [l[i] if (i % 3) != 0 else dummy for i in range(len(l))]
new_l = [i for i in new_l if i != dummy]

print(new_l)
```

Comment: Simpler: `[v for i, v in enumerate(l) if i % 3]`…